# this binding not working as expected in forEach arrow function

Tags: javascript

I have a class in which I bind some functions in the constructor. This works fine and as expected

```
class Row {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onEditRowClick = this.onEditRowClick.bind(this)
    this.onCommitRowClick = this.onCommitRowClick.bind(this)
    this.onDeleteRowClick = this.onDeleteRowClick.bind(this)
    this.onCellChange = this.onCellChange.bind(this)
  }
  ...
}
```

however, if I change to

```
class Row {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    let handlers = [this.onEditRowClick, this.onCommitRowClick, this.onCellChange, this.onDeleteRowClick]
    handlers.forEach(handler => {handler = handler.bind(this)})
  }
  ...
}
```

it is clearly not working as I get exceptions indicating that `this` in my function invocations is `null`.

I thought arrow functions implemented a lexical `this` binding?

Also, if I do this

```
class Row {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    [this.onEditRowClick, this.onCommitRowClick, this.onCellChange, this.onDeleteRowClick].forEach(handler => {handler = handler.bind(this)})
  }
}
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

while [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ammarcse/de7sdnzr/) is totally fine

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(item){console.log(item)})
```

Maybe Im missing something very obvious and it's time for me to go to bed?

Comment: You are assigning back to the parameter. That won't change the value of the variable / property you passed into the function. Take this simple example: `var foo = 42; (function(bar) { bar = 21; }(foo));`. `foo` still has the value `42`. Actually, you already have that problem with the array itself. Again a simplified example: `var foo = 42; var bar = [foo]; bar[0] = 21;`. `foo` still has the value `42`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) creates new function from the existing one which is bound to the passed context. Therefore you reassign properties in your first working example:

```
this.onEditRowClick = this.onEditRowClick.bind(this);
```

However in your latter example you skipped the reassign phase.
To solve this you can iterate over method names, bind it to the `this` instance and reassign:

```
class Row {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    let handlers = [
      'onEditRowClick',
      'onCommitRowClick',
      'onCellChange',
      'onDeleteRowClick'
    ];

    handlers.forEach(handler => {
        this[handler] = this[handler].bind(this);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: hey thanks! your answer is working. However, there is something I cannot wrap my head around...when I do `[this.onEditRowClick, ...`, am I not storing the *reference* to the function in an array such that `handler => {handler = handler.bind(this)}` should be sufficient?

Comment: actually, I think the way references work, you cannot reassign the source itself from a reference point of view, only mutate its internals, is that it?

Comment: on the `handler = handler.bind(this)` you're not reassigning the instance method on the `Row instance`, you're reassigning the value of the temporal variable `handler` inside the `forEach` scope. Hope it helps to understand better why this solution works

Comment: @sminutoli, it definitely does. I was changing the array instances, not the `Row` instance. Thanks for your help guys! :-)